# What is wrong with my multipart/form-data request?

Tags: request, esp32

I have a multipart/form-data request which at first looked good to me.

```
POST https://the.url.com/api/upload/ HTTP/1.1
Host: https://the.url.com
Authorization: Token 72356fadb7f12db755c704bafb7a1e5094eb089d00b25202095585704753724f
Content-Length: 50042
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=X-Hab_Image

--X-Hab_Image
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename= "photo.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

**here lies my image data**
--X-Hab_Image
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="device"

2
--X-Hab_Image
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="timestamp"

2023-04-16T22:57:45
--X-Hab_Image--
```

But django has trouble to recognize the *timestamp* as data

`request.data().get("timestamp")`

I also tried to define the timestamp as text, which did not help either:

```
...
...
--X-Hab_Image
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="timestamp"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset= "UTF-8"

2023-04-16T23:46:24
--X-Hab_Image--
```

Does anybody stumbled across a similar issue and knows what to do?
Is something wrong with my request?

Thank you